# Performance function call vs multiplication by 1

Tags: c++, performance, real-time

Look at this function:

```
float process(float in) {
  float out = in;

  for (int i = 0; i < 31; ++i) {
    if (biquads_[i]) {
      out = biquads_[i]->filter(out);
    }
  }

  return out;
}
```

`biquads_` is a `std::optional<Biquad>[31]`.

in this case i check for every optional to check if its not empty, and then call the filter function of biquad, if instead I unconditionally call filter function, changing it to multiply by 1 or simply return the input value, would be more efficient?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *if instead I unconditionally call filter function, changing it to multiply by 1 or simply return the input value, would be more efficient?* some more?

Comment: I don't have any numbers to back it up, but I would say the performance would be very similar, and the way you're doing it now it way clearer than the alternative.

Comment: You can get a better idea of the performance by displaying the assembly language generated by the compiler for both cases.

Comment: _The behavior is undefined if *this does not contain a value._ where _*this_ refers to the `optional` object. Therefore, you cannot unconditionally call the `filter` function.

Comment: by _unconditionally call filter function_ I mean change to a array of biquad instead of array optional. and then in the _process_ function remove _if (biquads_[i])_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most likely* it won't make a shread of difference (guessing somewhat though since your question is not entirely clear). For two reasons: 1) unless the code is going to be used in a *very* hot path, it won't matter even if one way is a few nanoseconds faster than the other. 2) most likely your compilers optimizer will be clever enough to generate code that performs close-to (if not identical to) the same in both cases. Did you test it? Did you benchmark/profile it? If not; do so - *with* optimization enabled.

Strive to write clear, readable, maintainable code. Worry about micro-optimization later when you actually have a problem and your profiler points to your function as a hot-spot.